Extra long ceiling fan brace for 30” joist spacing?
I am trying to convert my glass dome ceiling light fixture into a ceiling fan. I removed the light and plastic electrical box. Now there is just a 4" hole and wire.
I bought a retrofit Westinghouse ceiling fan brace kit, which fits joists 16-24", with a telescoping brace and metal teeth to dig into joists.
But my ceiling joists are 30" apart (old 1925 three-decker building, plaster and lath ceiling, and old joists at 30").
Searching ceiling fan braces, they all seem to be 16-24" max length. Any suggestions here to find a longer brace?
All I have is 4" hole to work with - no attic access - so can't build any other support without breaking through the ceiling. Thoughts or suggestions or workaround?

One possibility (to save the lathe and plaster ceiling) would be to cut the brace in the middle with a hack saw and insert 8" or 10" length of bar stock or heavy tubing in the middle. The tubing would be attached with JB Weld or equivalent.

How heavy is the fan? How high above the floor is the ceiling?  Is there a vertical obstruction above the ceiling that would limit the length of bar that could be inserted from below?

Is the hole in the ceiling close to one ceiling joist? Usually ceiling boxes for light fixtures are fastened to the side of a joist. I believe the middle of the bar is hollow and devoid of any internal parts in these old work bars which adjust by rotating.

Seems fairly obvious that you're getting hung up by not wanting to do what needs to be done, and looking for a unicorn to avoid it. Unicorns are hard to come by. So:

Break through the ceiling
install suitable lumber at a spacing that works
install suitable fan brace
repair ceiling.


Seems a shame to break lathe and plaster ceiling. What about inprovising an extension to the support bracket or devising a 30" bracket that could be inserted from below.

If he has access to the attic crawlspace, it may be possible to install a couple 2x4s or a 2x6 from above. If not, he'll need to cut a large hole to install the 2x6 (avoid the wiring when cutting blindly into a ceiling! Make sure to turn off as many circuit breakers as you can!).

Protips for working with lath: Screw it down along the cut line before cutting. Cut with a saw that won't tear it loose. A fine-toothed circular saw would work, but the blade will be ruined. Shim the framing to accommodate 5/8" drywall as a patch material set flush with the plaster. Use eye and ear protection.

Install a surface-mount brace.
You could fashion a decorative, coordinating wood or metal brace to lap two joists underneath the plaster. Mount it with two or three heavy screws at each intersection. It could be a hardwood 1x8 or softwood 2x8 with shaped ends, for example, or it could be wrought iron, such as a repurposed window security bar.
Consider making it long enough so that the fan is centered, regardless of joist location. Done right it'll be inconspicuous, yet stable.
